# about spring boot Profile can not work

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, profiles

when I use command

> mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=web

my project is running,but `@Profile("web")` bean code not used,that only use 
properties which the bean write by

```
 @Profile("default")
```

how can I change for it,and the properties change to web profile?

```
@Profile("default")
@Bean
static public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer defaultPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resourceLocations = new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("job.core.properties") };
    p.setLocations(resourceLocations);
    return p;
}

@Profile("web")
@Bean
static public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prodWebPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resourceLocations = new Resource[] {new ClassPathResource("job.core.ris.properties") };
    p.setLocations(resourceLocations);
    return p;
}
```

> job.core.ris.properties

```
db.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.68:3306/job_ris?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
db.user=root
db.password=
```

> job.core.properties

```
db.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.68:3306/dev?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

when I use action then,show this
[image]

Comment: Why the `@Bean` annotated methods are static? Try to remove the `static`

Comment: if remove static  the jdbcUrl will be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with the framework not against/around it. Spring Boot has [build in support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) to load profile specific `application.properties` files.

Instead of trying to shoehorn multiple `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` into a Spring Boot application. Create an `application.properties` and `application-web.properties` containing your properties.

**application.properties**

```
db.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.68:3306/dev?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

**application-web.properties**

```
db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.68:3306/job_ris?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
db.user=root
db.password=
```

(notice the missing `db.driverClass` you only need to include the different properties).

Next remove your custom `@Bean` annotated methods and let Spring Boot do the heavy lifting.

**Pro Tip:** Judging from the names of the properties you also have a custom `@Bean` for your `DataSource`. Instead of using custom names you probably want to use the `spring.datasource.*` properties and let Spring Boot create/manage your datasource.

Comment: ok,I use this method  before,this will be done. Thanks always.